# fwrite(): send of 8192 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe'

Tags: php, сокет

Вот такую строку ошибки мне шлет PHP. Соединение открыто, пытаемся писать в сокет и на стороне сервера все падает. Весь интернет перекопал, что это может быть, как лечить.
Вообще есть идея создать дополнительный сервис, который будет следить за этим сервером сокетов и поднимать его если тот упал, но хотелось бы понять как вообще избежать этой ошибки.
И да, собачка перед fwrite() все решает, но непонятно куда денутся тогда данные.

Comment: Как же вы перекопали "весь интернет" - но так и не догадались написать в гугле "broken pipe"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ошибка "broken pipe" означает, что вы пытаетесь писать в канал, который на другой стороне был закрыт. Иными словами, клиент уже отвалился - а сервер все еще пытается передать ему какую-то информацию (или наоборот).

На стороне сервера такую ошибку надо обязательно обрабатывать (используйте try/catch) - ведь потеря соединения с клиентом не должна приводить к падению сервера.

Но первопричина ошибки - именно в отвалившемся клиенте.

Comment: Вот Павел ни одного внятного ответа так и не нашел, спасибо Вам. Из-за чего такое может происходить, обрыв соединения или клиент что то не отвечает, что должен ? Мне просто хочется понять как реагировать, после ошибки удалять соединение на сервере или пытаться его снова использовать ?

Comment: Удалять, разумеется. Как вы повторно используете оборвавшееся соединение?

Comment: А почему та же ошибка вылазит при работе с парой сокетов созданных функцией stream_socket_pair()

Comment: Потому что один из сокетов закрыт.